# HTML-CSS To top and to bottom of page buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some reason I am unable to show two buttons simultaneously on the page: a "to the top" button and a "to the bottom" button.

Changing some of the variables allows one of the two buttons, but never both at the same time. When the buttons show, they perform the action as expected - they just don't seem to be able to co-exist together with this code.

Thanks for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
...
<style>
  /* For to-top button */
            #myBtn {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 120px;
            left: 3.7px;
            z-index: 99;
            font-size: 18px;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            background-color: #4E2F8E;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 15px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            }

            #myBtn:hover {
            background-color: #CABCE5;
            color:#17043A;
            }

            /* For to-bottom button */
            #myBtn2 {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 6px;
            left: 3.7px;
            z-index: 99;
            font-size: 18px;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            background-color: #4E2F8E;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 15px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            }

            #myBtn2:hover {
            background-color: #CABCE5;
            color:#17043A;
            }

        </style>
 </head>
<body>
...

<!-- Go to top button -->
        <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i></button>
        <button onclick="bottomFunction()" id="myBtn2" title="Go to bottom"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"></i></button>
 
...

        <script>
            //Get the button
            var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

            
            // When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
            window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
            
            function scrollFunction() {
              if (document.body.scrollTop > 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
                mybutton.style.display = "block";
              } else {
                mybutton.style.display = "none";
              }
            }
            
            // When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
            function topFunction() {
              document.body.scrollTop = 0;
              document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
            }
            
            </script>

            <script>
            var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

            // When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
            window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
            
            function scrollFunction() {
              if (document.body.scrollTop > 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
                mybutton.style.display = "block";
              } else {
                mybutton.style.display = "none";
              }
            }

            // When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the bottom of the document
            function bottomFunction() {
              #window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
            }
            </script>

</body>
```

Comment: You're calling the `scrollFunction()` before defining it. Try moving it down. Not sure if this works. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following implementation. Not sure if it is what you are looking for, but surely is a good starting point.

```js
const body = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0];
const [buttonTop, buttonBottom] = document.querySelectorAll('button[type=button]');

const scrollingElement = document.scrollingElement || body;

const goTop = () => {
    scrollingElement.scrollTop = 0;
};

const goBottom = () => {
    scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;
};

const onScrollHandler = () => {
    if (scrollingElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        buttonTop.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        buttonTop.style.display = 'none';
    }

    if (scrollingElement.scrollTop > scrollingElement.scrollHeight - scrollingElement.clientHeight - 20) {
        buttonBottom.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        buttonBottom.style.display = 'block';
    }
}

buttonTop.addEventListener('click', goTop);
buttonBottom.addEventListener('click', goBottom);
window.addEventListener('scroll', onScrollHandler);

onScrollHandler();
```

```css
.root {
    height: 5000px;
}

.button-top,
.button-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    left: 4px;
    z-index: 99;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #4e2f8e;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.button-top {
    display: none;
    bottom: 120px;
}

.button-bottom {
    bottom: 6px;
}

.button-top:hover,
.button-bottom:hover {
    background-color: #cabce5;
    color: #17043a;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <title>NO TITLE</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="root">
        <h1>SCROLL ME</h1>
        <button type="button" class="button-top" title="Go to top"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-up">TOP</i></button>
        <button type="button" class="button-bottom" title="Go to bottom"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down">BOTTOM</i></button>
    </div>
</body>
```